# After SSH connection is enabled in Java, how can I invoke CMD multiple times in the same session?

Tags: java, ssh

Jar download address  http://www.ganymed.ethz.ch/ssh2/
I use the JAR package method (Ganymed SSH-2 for Java) to connect SSH. After the connection is created and successfully connected and verified, a session is opened through the connection object, and the execCommand method of this session is invoked to execute CMD command.My requirement: call the command periodically and return the result. In the following code, I can successfully execute the command continuously in while and get the return value, but I need to open and close the session every time. If the session is not closed in while, I can only call it for ten times and then exit with an exception.Since the way I close the session will affect the efficiency of data acquisition, my question is how can I execute the command repeatedly after opening a session with no limit on the number of times?

```java
@Test
    public void mainTest(){
        String ip = "192.168.21.137";
        String username = "hadoop";
        String password = "hadoop";

        String chartset = "UTF-8";

        Connection connection = null;

        //Start by passing in an IP address to log in to
        try {
            connection = new Connection(ip);
            connection.connect();
            boolean isAuthenticated = connection.authenticateWithPassword(username, password);
            if (isAuthenticated) {
                System.out.println(ip+"Connection made");
            } else {
                throw new Exception(ip+"Connection failed");
            }
            //Write the command to a script before executing the script
            String cmd = "top -b -n 1 | sed -n '3,4p';"+"df;";
//            String  cmd = "top -b -n 1 | head -n 5";

            while(true){
                Session session = null;
                session = connection.openSession();//Open session
                session.execCommand(cmd);
                   //Get the standard output stream
                InputStream inputStreams = new StreamGobbler(session.getStdout());
                BufferedReader brs = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStreams, chartset));
                List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
                for (String line = brs.readLine(); line != null; line = brs.readLine(),i++) {
                    result.add(line);
                   System.out.println(line);
                if(result.size() ==0) {
                    System.out.println(result);
                }
                session.waitForCondition(ChannelCondition.CLOSED | ChannelCondition.EOF | ChannelCondition.EXIT_STATUS, 1000 * 3600);
                System.out.println("ExitCode: " + session.getExitStatus()); //If the script is successfully executed, 0 is successful and non-0 is failed
                if (session != null) {//The session must be closed. Otherwise, an error message will be displayed after the session is opened for ten times
                    session.close();
                }
                Thread.sleep(2000);
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (connection != null) {
                connection.close();
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: You mentioned that after executing 10 times, i.e. after 2000 * 10 milliseconds or 20 seconds an exception is thrown. What is that exception message? Is that a timeout for SSH session? If yes, then maybe you should check how you can increase the timeout.

Comment: I have tried to change the sleep time to adjust the interval, but it can only output ten times;Here is the exception thrown after ten outputs:  
 
 ```java.io.IOException: Could not open channel (The server refused to open the channel (SSH_OPEN_ADMINISTRATIVELY_PROHIBITED, 'open failed'))
 at ch.ethz.ssh2.channel.ChannelManager.waitUntilChannelOpen(ChannelManager.java:123)
 at ch.ethz.ssh2.channel.ChannelManager.openSessionChannel(ChannelManager.java:568)
 at ch.ethz.ssh2.Session.<init>(Session.java:39)
 at ch.ethz.ssh2.Connection.openSession(Connection.java:965)```

Comment: I wondered how I could initialize a session only once and then call ```session.execcommand (cmd)``` multiple times to get the data returned.

Comment: Your SSH server is probably rejecting your SSH client's request to open a channel.

Comment: I think it is because the session is not closed in the while that the server denies access. However, at the beginning of the while, the connection object is used to initialize a session each time. I suspect that it is similar to thread opening.An exception is thrown for memory overflow caused by multiple threads (or sessions) being opened and not closed.If I initialize and close the session in a while, the server does not deny access and can keep executing. To improve efficiency of the while, I want to initialize and close the session only once, but do not know how to use the SSH2 library.

Comment: Can you try opening the session before while loop and closing it after the while loop?

Comment: I tried to initialize and close the session before and after the while, but the session. ExecCommand (CMD) executed in the while;Can only be executed once, and a second execution in the while throws an exception: ```java.io.IOException:A remote execution has already started.
at ch.ethz.ssh2.Session.execCommand(Session.java:244)
at com.lsx.monitorsys.connectSSh.connect.mainTest(connect.java:59)```

Comment: After I look at the library again, there is a variable in the method of executing CMD to determine whether the CMD command is already executing. I try to reset this variable in the hope that I can execute the method again, but I find that I can't.

Comment: Maybe you can add this code of the library of execCommand in the post. Maybe the library has some bug wherein, this flag isn't reset after a command has completed execution. It's strange that a session needs to be reopened for each command.

Comment: ```    public void execCommand(String cmd) throws IOException {
        if (cmd == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("cmd argument may not be null");
        } else {
            synchronized(this) {
                if (this.flag_closed) {
                    throw new IOException("This session is closed."); }
                if (this.flag_execution_started) {
                    throw new IOException("A remote execution has already started."); }
                this.flag_execution_started = true; }
            this.cm.requestExecCommand(this.cn, cmd);  }}    ```

Comment: Flag_execution_started has a property in this entity. I don't know how to override it

Comment: You need to explore the library code and find the references of that flag and check where it's set.